# Android device breakdown

Tags: android

I know that [the dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) provided by Google provides a breakdown for screen size and OpenGL version. Is there anywhere I can find statistics on percentage of devices? E.g.: 10% Galaxy S2, 5% Nexus, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Google does not provide this information, there are third party sources which provide these statistics for the devices which they track (though they're not comprehensive, just a "all of the top ___ devices"). Most notably, Flurry [published this](http://blog.flurry.com/bid/85911/App-Developers-Signal-Apple-Allegiance-Ahead-of-WWDC-and-Google-I-O) (now slightly out of date) chart:

[image: Distribution of User Sessions by Top 20 Android Devices from Flurry]

Though note that this chart is by sessions and not simply by device.

AppBrain also [provides a graph along with a more detailed set of these statistics](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-phones):

[image: AppBrain's Top Android Phones]

In the Google Play Developer Console you can also find these statistics specific to your app, and other services including Flurry can also provide you this data if you instrument your app with their SDK. Some of them give a more detailed list of devices as well via CSV export.

Comment: Thanks! The Flurry data is actually helpful even though it's by sessions. The AppBrain data on the other hand only covers devices that uses their app so not sure how representative it is.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't. For apps in the Play Store, you can find the % of the top 10 devices which use your app. Aside from this, there is no Android phone market share diagram/data. (It wouldn't be much help anyway; there are over 3,000 types of Android devices.)

Comment: If you export the data from the Developer Console to CSV format, the `<app-name>_device_installs.csv` file list all of the devices and not just the top 10.

Comment: @Squonk Very nice! I never knew that...